# Running servlet in background based on Request in Java

Tags: java, servlets

I have two application servers say A and B. I will send a request to particular servlet of application server B from A and return back. I dont want to get any response from B. But on application server B, based on the request and the information from that request (say username) I want to search a data and write it into a file.

- I tried to execute using shell script
- Tried threads

But the execution time takes too long in Java.

In simple, how to send  many GET request from application server A to application server B, so application server B will execute in its background and A need not wait for response.

Comment: @Rajesh interesting *possible duplicate* question but useless. HTTP requests are synchronous, so the only way to not *wait for their response* is through an async call like using a separate thread to start the call.

Comment: Both application server A and application server B is having only Java. I am sending from one servlet of A application server to another servlet of B application. The duplicate shown gives example of sending request from JS (AJAX) to Java server.

Comment: What's your real concern here: how to make an asynchronous call to your servlet or how to improve the execution time of the servlet request in A?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is there a duplicate question, in which the server ( application server B) is functioning fully in async mode.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if I make asynchronous call, then automatically I can reduce the waiting time in A.

Comment: Use a [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) then.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you tried, but it can easily be done. I recommend to structure it this way:

1. As said above server A performs a GET toward a specific servlet on server B
2. The work you need to perform on server B, let's call it a *job*, it's essentially reading something from a DB using a username that server A sent you and then writing something on a file.
3. The servlet on server B will enqueue a new job (a `Runnable` with your job code in it) on a preconfigured `ThreadPool` **AND** return **IMMEDIATELY**.

   I guess you want the jobs to be performed *sequentially*, so just create a `ThreadPool` of size 1 (with a single thread that will execute your jobs one after another).

That should be a good enough architecture for what you are trying to do.

If your server A GET call is still blocking, maybe the issue is related to  how you perform this get. If you notice that the GET duration seems always the same, it's likely that you didn't configure correctly your `HttpURLConnection` (http server dependent, e.g. some configurations could require additional headers to disable default keep-alive connections).

Also, remember to always disconnect your `urlconnection` (`urlconnection` are usually reused, this frees the resource) in a `finally` block.